# Html, Css , padding-top is not working

Tags: html, css

The padding-top in nav a doesn't fit 
I want to have this

[image]

but I actually get this

[image]

here is my html and css code

```css
body{
 background-image: url('img/bg.png');
 color:#000305;
 font-size:87.5%;
 font-family:Arial, 'Licida Sans Unicode';
 text-align:left;
 }
 
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

a:link, a:visited{

}

a:hover, a:active{

}

.body{
 clear:both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:70%; 
}

.mainHeader img{
 width:30%;
 height:auto;
 margin:2% 0;
}

.mainHeader nav{
 background-color: #666;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;

}

.mainHeader nav ul li{
 float : left;
 display:inline;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited{
 color: #FFF;
 display:inlin-block;
 padding:10px 25px;
 height:20px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active  a:link, .mainHeader nav .active  a:visited{
 background-color:#CF5C3F;
 text-shadow:none;

}

.mainHeader nav ul li a{
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
  <img src="img/css.jpg" />
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Why is it so?

Comment: It's good practice to reduce your HTML and CSS to the absolute minimum required to reproduce the problem, rather than including everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.mainHeader nav ul li` to `display: block`. You also had a typo in your child anchor tags which should have read `display: inline-block;`. I've added comments of what I've changed.

```css
body{
 background-image: url('img/bg.png');
 color:#000305;
 font-size:87.5%;
 font-family:Arial, 'Licida Sans Unicode';
 text-align:left;
 }
 
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

a:link, a:visited{}

a:hover, a:active{}

.body{
 clear:both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:70%; 
}

.mainHeader img{
 width:30%;
 height:auto;
 margin:2% 0;
}

.mainHeader nav{
 background-color: #666;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li{
 float : left;
 display: block; /* I CHANGED THIS */ 
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited{
 color: #FFF;
 display:inline-block; /* I CHANGED THIS */ 
    padding:10px 25px;
 height:20px;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active  a:link, .mainHeader nav .active  a:visited{
 background-color:#CF5C3F;
 text-shadow:none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a{
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
  <img src="img/css.jpg" />
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ul css codes to this:

```
.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution: avoid using float, and use display:table-cell

```css
body{
 background-image: url('img/bg.png');
 color:#000305;
 font-size:87.5%;
 font-family:Arial, 'Licida Sans Unicode';
 text-align:left;
 }
 
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

a:link, a:visited{

}

a:hover, a:active{

}

.body{
 clear:both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:70%; 
}

.mainHeader img{
 width:30%;
 height:auto;
 margin:2% 0;
}

.mainHeader nav{
 background-color: #666;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;
    height: 40px;

    display: table-cell; /*ADD THIS*/
    vertical-align: middle; /*ADD THIS*/

}

.mainHeader nav ul li{
 
 display: inline-block; /*ADD THIS*/
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited{
 color: #FFF;
 display:inlin-block;
 padding:10px 25px;
 height:20px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active  a:link, .mainHeader nav .active  a:visited{
 background-color:#CF5C3F;
 text-shadow:none;

}

.mainHeader nav ul li a{
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>HTML And CSS Responsive</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body">
 <header class="mainHeader">
  <img src="img/css.jpg"/>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
 <div class="mainContent">
  <div class="content">
   <article title="top content">
    <header>
     <h2><a href="#" title="first post"> First post</a></h2>
    </header>
    <footer>
     <p class="post-info">This text is written by christian</p>
    </footer>
    <content>
    <p>This course is built to teach beginners how to start making applications in Android,
    as well as for advanced devs to learn some of the advanced features available in Mobile Application Development.</p>
    <p>It's a simple code along tutorial series where students can code while learning, which is found to be the most efficient way of learning these days.</p>
    </content>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <aside class="top-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Top sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>
 
 <aside class="middle-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Middle sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>
 
 <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Bottom sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>

 <footer class="mainFooter">
  <p>Copyrigt &copy; 2016<a href="#" title="ferdaous.com">Ferdaous.com</a></p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body{
 background-image: url('img/bg.png');
 color:#000305;
 font-size:87.5%;
 font-family:Arial, 'Licida Sans Unicode';
 text-align:left;
 }
 
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

a:link, a:visited{

}

a:hover, a:active{

}

.body{
 clear:both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:70%; 
}

.mainHeader img{
 width:30%;
 height:auto;
 margin:2% 0;
}

.mainHeader nav{
 background-color: #666;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;
  height: 40px; /*fix height*/
    display: table-cell;  /*display as table-cell*/
    vertical-align: middle;  /*center vertically*/

}

.mainHeader nav ul li{
 
 display:inline-block;  /*CHANGE To display-inline*/
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited{
 color: #FFF;
 display:inlin-block;
 padding:10px 25px;
 height:20px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active  a:link, .mainHeader nav .active  a:visited{
 background-color:#CF5C3F;
 text-shadow:none;

}

.mainHeader nav ul li a{
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>HTML And CSS Responsive</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body">
 <header class="mainHeader">
  <img src="img/css.jpg"/>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
 <div class="mainContent">
  <div class="content">
   <article title="top content">
    <header>
     <h2><a href="#" title="first post"> First post</a></h2>
    </header>
    <footer>
     <p class="post-info">This text is written by christian</p>
    </footer>
    <content>
    <p>This course is built to teach beginners how to start making applications in Android,
    as well as for advanced devs to learn some of the advanced features available in Mobile Application Development.</p>
    <p>It's a simple code along tutorial series where students can code while learning, which is found to be the most efficient way of learning these days.</p>
    </content>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <aside class="top-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Top sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>
 
 <aside class="middle-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Middle sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>
 
 <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Bottom sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>

 <footer class="mainFooter">
  <p>Copyrigt &copy; 2016<a href="#" title="ferdaous.com">Ferdaous.com</a></p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add `line-height` to the `li` the same height as the `nav` div.

```
.mainHeader nav ul li{
    float : left;
    display:inline;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9zrdt89/)

```css
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.mainHeader img{
 width:30%;
 height:auto;
 margin:2% 0;
}

.mainHeader nav{
 background-color: #666;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li{
 float : left;
 display:inline;
 line-height: 40px;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited{
 color: #FFF;
 display:inlin-block;
 padding:10px 25px;
 height:20px;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active  a:link, .mainHeader nav .active  a:visited{
 background-color:#CF5C3F;
 text-shadow:none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a{
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
  <img src="img/css.jpg"/>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding to `ul` element.

```css
body{
 background-image: url('img/bg.png');
 color:#000305;
 font-size:87.5%;
 font-family:Arial, 'Licida Sans Unicode';
 text-align:left;
 }
 
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

a:link, a:visited{

}

a:hover, a:active{

}

.body{
 clear:both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:70%; 
}

.mainHeader img{
 width:30%;
 height:auto;
 margin:2% 0;
}

.mainHeader nav{
 background-color: #666;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav ul{
 list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
 margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:12px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li{
 
 display:inline-block;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited{
 color: #FFF;
 display:inlin-block;
 padding:10px 25px;
 height:20px;
 
 
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active  a:link, .mainHeader nav .active  a:visited{
 background-color:#CF5C3F;
 text-shadow:none;

}

.mainHeader nav ul li a{
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>HTML And CSS Responsive</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body">
 <header class="mainHeader">
  <img src="img/css.jpg"/>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
 <div class="mainContent">
  <div class="content">
   <article title="top content">
    <header>
     <h2><a href="#" title="first post"> First post</a></h2>
    </header>
    <footer>
     <p class="post-info">This text is written by christian</p>
    </footer>
    <content>
    <p>This course is built to teach beginners how to start making applications in Android,
    as well as for advanced devs to learn some of the advanced features available in Mobile Application Development.</p>
    <p>It's a simple code along tutorial series where students can code while learning, which is found to be the most efficient way of learning these days.</p>
    </content>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <aside class="top-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Top sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>
 
 <aside class="middle-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Middle sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>
 
 <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
  <article>
   <h2>Bottom sidebar</a></h2>
   <p>This is what Foundation can do along with several other frameworks that focus on making websites responsive for mobile devices.</p>
  </article>
 </aside>

 <footer class="mainFooter">
  <p>Copyrigt &copy; 2016<a href="#" title="ferdaous.com">Ferdaous.com</a></p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```